# Looking for a maximal inequality for supermartingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I wonder if there are any $L_p$ maximal inequalities for supermartingales. Specifically, for a non-negative supermartingale $\{X_n\}$ and $p\geq 1$, is there any $A_p, B_p>0$ such that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{0\leq k\leq n} |X_k|^p\right] \leq A_p \mathbb{E}\left[ |X_0|^p\right] + B_p \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^p] .$$

Or is there any inequalities so that we can bound the LHS?

Comment: Yes, there is a similar inequality for supermartingales.  The proof is almost the same as the one for submartingales, so you might want to try looking at the proof of the inequality for submartingales and seeing if you can generalize it.

Comment: @user6247850 It will be extremely helpful if you can point me to any reference of it. The only trouble I have is the convex function of a supermartingale is no longer a supermartingale.

Comment: Sorry, I may have made a mistake - I was thinking of only $L^1$

Comment: $L^1$ is also fine. I don't really need all $p\geq 1$.